# Did 93,000 Pakistan Army soldiers surrender in 1971?

Tags: military, pakistan

- [When 93,000 Pakistani soldiers surrendered before Indian Army](https://zeenews.india.com/video/india/when-93000-pakistani-soldiers-surrendered-before-indian-army-2550467.html)
- [49 Years Ago, 93,000 Pakistani Soldiers Surrendered To India; Here’s All You Need To Know](https://news.abplive.com/news/india/vijay-diwas-2020-why-is-vijay-diwas-celebrated-all-about-history-and-significance-of-vijay-diwas-1413171)
- [Pakistani Instrument of Surrender](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pakistani_Instrument_of_Surrender)

It is frequently written and said that 93,000 Pakistani **soldiers** surrendered in 1971. What is the source of this figure?

Two references are used in the Wikipedia article to support that figure. One is an Indian newspaper, and the other is a book that doesn't quote the same figure.

Also, there is confusion about whether all 93,000 personnel were West-Pakistani military personnel or a mix of military, locally recruited paramilitary [(Razakar) forces](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Razakar_(Pakistan)), or civilians.

If it was a mix, how many of them were actual military service personnel from the Pakistan Army?

- https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=xQb6mhgBVmE

This British documentary says that there were 24,000 soldiers.

**Related:** [Was the 1971 Pakistani surrender in Bangladesh the first public surrender in history?](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/45895/was-the-1971-pakistani-surrender-in-bangladesh-the-first-public-surrender-in-his/47175#47175)

Comment: To avoid getting into a semantic argument about the meaning of "soldier", an answer with a breakdown of regular army vs paramilitary personnel would be a good answer.

Comment: In some, now deleted, comments there was a call for sources based on their religion or nationality to provide a "balance". Just a reminder that this is a [fallacy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/False_balance) and trust in answers should be based on evidence, not creed.

Answer (score 4):

Other sources such as [Kashmir Politics and Imperialist Manoeuvres, 1846-1980](https://www.google.com/books/edition/Kashmir_Politics_and_Imperialist_Manoeuv/UPALAAAAIAAJ?hl=en&gbpv=0&bsq=pakistan%2074000%20soldiers%20surrender%201971) (1988) say that on 16 December 1971, "74,000 military personnel and 16,000 civilians and their families surrendered to the Joint Indo-Bangladesh Army Command".

Confirming the 90,000 number from the Pakistani side, the 16 December 1972 (Zul-Qi'dah 10, 1392) [Pakistan Affairs](https://www.google.com/books/edition/Pakistan_Affairs/6VI8AQAAIAAJ?hl=en&gbpv=1&dq=pakistan%2090000%20pows&pg=PP374&printsec=frontcover), Volume XXV, Number 20 (which was a publication of the Embassy of Pakistan in Washington, DC) says:

> ...on the occasion of Human Rights Day, the Government of Pakistan has reminded the world that over 90,000 Pakistani prisoners of war and civilian internees continue to suffer in Indian detention

(Another issue of *Pakistan Affairs*, [16 November 1972 issue](https://www.google.com/books/edition/Pakistan_Affairs/6VI8AQAAIAAJ?hl=en&gbpv=1&dq=pakistan%2093000%20pows&pg=PP367&printsec=frontcover), says 93000 instead of 90000 and specifies that 10000-20000 of those are civilians, quoting from a 6 November 1972 Christian Science Monitor article that is advocating for the release of the Pakistani POWs.)